# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in linux anaconda environment

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tensorflow

> A. Background:

1.Because I need to use GPU to run a python file for deep learning practice. And this python file had been running in google colab successfully.
2.And I tried to run other python file to see whether the result would be core dumped or not. That's true. I found the result is same even I running different py.file.
3.***So I guess my shell scripts would be some problems***. If my anaconda, tensorflow and python are matched version in linux virtual environment.

> B.What I searched for solving this issue.

1.some people said I need to use the command unlimited -c to check something. it seems okay.
2.I have read some issue case and it said the core dumped may connect to the code/memory, but code can be running in jupyter notebook/colab and GPU memory is okay because this is school's GPU.others didn't meet this issue.

> 3. My shell scripts.
>    I made a shell scripts below and use the qsub to submit the shell scrip. and the virtual anaconda environment name is edward so I ACTIVATED IT. and the python file is cwgan-gp.learning.py. and it will read a txt file in this python file to predict something.  Any problem??

```
#!/bin/sh
#$ -S /bin/sh
#$ -l h_vmem=3G
#$ -l mem_req=3G
#$ -cwd
#$ -e eerror.txt
#$ -o ooutput.txt



source ~/local/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate edward

python3  /home/edward/archive/cwgan-gp.learning.py
```

when I submit the file it will give me a core dumped result and a core.1134 file. and other python file would be get the same feedback. How can I do???

Comment: Use `ulimt -a` instead of `ulimit -c`. This will check the system resources limit for your user. If you are unsure of the meaning of the output, update your question with it.

Comment: core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 2060765
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 131072
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited

Comment: virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 4194304
file locks                      (-x) unlimited